# How to pull variables from line of data file in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a large data file where each row looks as follows, where each pipe-delimited value represents a consistent variable (i.e. 1517892812 and 1517892086 represent the Unix Timestamp, and the last pipe delimited object will always be UnixTimestamp)

```
264|2|8|6|1.32235000|1.33070000|1.31400000|1257.89480966|1517892812
399|10|36|2|1.12329614|1.12659227|1.12000000|148194.47200218|1517892086
```

How can I pull out the values I need to make variables in Python? For example, looking at a row and getting UnixTimestamp=1517892812 (and other variables) out of it.

I want to pull out each relevant variable per line, work with them, and then look at the next line and reevaluate all of the variable values.

Is RegEx what I should be dealing with here?

Comment: Use the csv module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regex, you can use `split()`:

```
int(a.strip().split('|')[-1])
```

Comment: That is very simple and straightforward.

Comment: @JoshGoodnow Please don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your problem. Just click the checkbox on the left.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, I cannot accept the answer for 7 more minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If all variable are only number and you want a matrix whit all your values you can simply do something like:

[int(line.strip().split('|')) for line in your_data.splitlines()]

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and `re.search()`:

```
int(re.search(r'[^|]+$', text).group())
```